# how can I call a class without passing driver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to create a callable class that clicks on an element and waits until a new element appears. this is what I have:

```
class ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement:
driver = None

def __init__(self, locator, element_to_appear):
    self.locator = locator
    self.element_to_appear = element_to_appear

def __call__(self, driver=None):
    if driver is None:
        driver = self.driver

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.locator)))
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.locator)
    element.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.element_to_appear)))
```

this is how I use the class on the page class where I define all my page objects:

```
 choose_timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago = ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(
    '//select[@id="timesheet_id"]//option[contains(.,"3")]',
    '//th[@class="workday"]//div[contains(.,"3")]')
```

this works but only if I pass "driver" on the test:

```
    def test_worker_not_included_after_delete_out_punch(self):
        self.login_page.login('rsediqi@dexcom-demo.com', 'rsediqi')
        self.worker_list_page.workers_menu.click()
        self.worker_list_page.filter_by_name_label = 'Eli Gritz'
        self.worker_list_page.choose_worker = 'Eli Gritz'
        self.worker_drill_down_page.choose_timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago(self.driver)
```

is there any way to not pass the self.driver and just call the element? not really sure what I need to change , I just want something like this on my test:

```
   self.worker_drill_down_page.choose_timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `driver` a default value of `None`, then change a `None`-valued argument to `self.driver`.

```
def __call__(self, driver=None):
    if driver is None:
        driver = self.driver

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.locator)))
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.locator)
    element.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.element_to_appear)))
```

Comment: thanks for your help @chepner but I'm seeing an error:
E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: You need a driver from *some* where, right? I (mistakenly) assumed you passed a driver to `__init__` when you created the instance.

Comment: I edited the question code to what I have right now(including your suggestion) @chepner

Comment: I'm not familiar with`selenium`: the question is, where does `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement` get instantiated? You have to at least set the class attribute `driver` to valid driver so that `self.driver` has a non-`None` value when `__call__` gets called without an argument.